# Correct application design: data reading and UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

this could be a long question, I'll do my best to ask it properly.

I want to read large .txt files with lots of numerical data. In each file there will be "channels" (30-50 channels, with own name, axis units, and of course, data). So I've created a `class Channel` with that properties, and a `class File` that has a list of that channels. It also has a method that reads the file and stores everything in lists.

I want to be able to load several files at the same time, and for that I've created a `UserControl` that consists in a button for loading the file and a `ComboBox` that displays each channel:

[image]
(The `ComboBox` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`)
The data is stored in the code behind of the user control. So when I insert in my `MainWindow` several `UserControls` I can't access that data.

What I want is have several UserControl...

[image]

...and be able to plot the data from each one in that Plotter, and be capable of some control (previous, next..)

[image]

My first approach was to store everything in the `UserControl`, that was easy to do but ineffective.
So what I figured out that might be the solution is to store everything in other place and then access to there from the MainWindow or other place. I've tried VERY HARD to learn MVVM and use it in my project. But I must be very STUPID because I can't get it.

My new approach is described in the next scheme:

[image]

My questions:

1.Is this the correct way of doing it? If the MVVM is the way, please, I beg you, please, guide me just a little bit in the beginning, because I am not capable to translate that intricate examples out there of MVVM to my project.

2.If I'm doing it more or less right, how could I store all that data in some other place and the access it from `MainWindow`? (in my File class I have a method that stores all in lists, so in my UserControl I have the "Browse" button that gets a filename, and then with the read() method I store everything inside (?) the `File class`, or at least inside the place I've created the new File: the `UserControl`).

I'll post code, pics, more info, anything if needed. Thanks.

Comment: This is how questions should be asked on SO, what an effort, +1 =]

Comment: I would implement this as a Sorted List of ViewModels that mapped 1 to 1 to the controls and provided their context.  MVVM is made for this sort of thing because your app needs to be upwardly scalable and other approaches will become difficult to manage.  I have a small reference implementation at https://tyburnprismpassword.codeplex.com/ which you can download the source and check out.  I recommend "Pro WPF and
Silverlight MVVM" for the theory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the MVVM is the way, please, I beg you, please, guide me just a little bit in the beginning, because I am not capable to translate that intricate examples out there of MVVM to my project.

You're already half-way to using something that's MVVM, at least in nature.  It isn't "the way", but it would definitely be **a** (reasonably nice) way to handle this.

In order to design this with an MVVM type of design, you'd want to make your "MY DATA" class be the `DataContext` of the UserControl.  All of the data would be stored there (preferrably in `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`, as that will handle binding more effectively).

Your "UserControl1" portion would likely be some form of ItemsControl, bound to a collection of sources.  The selected item could then be bound to something on your "MY DATA" class, which determined which "plot" should be displayed.

To answer your questions directly:

> 1.Is this the correct way of doing it?

This is definitely a step in the right directly.  Storing your data separate from your controls is one of the key pillars to making your application more flexible and maintainable (and a large goal of MVVM).

> 2.If I'm doing it more or less right, how could I store all that data in some other place and the access it from MainWindow?

You handle this by setting the class as the `DataContext` of your UserControl and/or `MainWindow`.  This allows you to bind to properties on your data class (which is effectively your ViewModel in MVVM terminology).

---

Also, I know you've tried to study and learn MVVM - and it's difficult to grasp initially, but it is worth the effort.  I will say that your design scenario (which is effectively a list of "options" on the left, and a "detail" pane on the right) is not an uncommon one - it's actually similar to my example in my [blog series on MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/), and should be fairly easy to create once you understand the basics.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've been trying to implement this thing and I have a basic issue. I don't know where and how store data. I've read that Model is the place for that (but in other places says that its only a definition of the classes of the data). If I create a class for that I have to instantiate it and that means that I can't have access to it from some other place. If I set it static I can't bind. One of my problems is that I don't know how to read the file properly: where to store all that data. My read() method is part of the File class, so that restricts its scope.

Comment: @Sturm Typically, the "main" ViewModel class will take care of instantiating the data/types, and orchestrate passing this into the other classes.  It's the "glue" that holds everything together.